# is it possible to store files in directories in yammer?

Tags: directory, yammer

I can see that it is possible to upload files to be shared in the network, but if the subjets covered by the group are diverse, it might be interesting to put the files in distinct directory. (I am aware of the tagging option)

Answer (score 0):

Yammer supports file uploads, but its primary focus is not as a file repository. If you are already managing files in your app, and are integrating with Yammer then you are much better to post messages to Yammer with [Open Graph metadata](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/open-graph) attached. The OG metadata points to the URL that hosts the files in your application. That way you avoid duplication of files in Yammer and your application. The *og_* methods on the [messages](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post) endpoint are a useful starting point.

Comment: Thank you, I am much more beginner than that, I was just beginning to use it at work in a group, and was experiencing the tool, which is great except for this impossibility to tidy up the files. I found my answer on the official website though "Regarding your first inquiry on organizing files that have been posted, this is a current product limitation on Yammer. Files cannot be organized into folders or arranged into any particular order other than type"